# Azure Web App cannot send email from smtp.office365.com

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, smtp, office365

I'm trying to send email from Azure Web App using Office365. Later, we'll move it to Azure Web Job or Azure Functions.

The following sample code works in ***local development machine***, as well as in Azure using ***on-premise SMTP server at same port 587***. However, the same credentials as local machine throws the exception from ***smtp.office365.com*** in Azure.

***It seems like the problem lies between Azure and Office 365.*** Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Sending email from an Azure App Service using an O365 SMTP server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/01/11/sending-email-from-an-azure-web-app-using-an-o365-smtp-server/)

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("To Email Address", "Benjamin"));
msg.From = new MailAddress("From Email Address", "You");
msg.Subject = "Azure Web App Email using smtp.office365.com";
msg.Body = "Test message using smtp.office365.com on Azure from a Web App";
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("O365 UID", "O365 PASS");
client.Port = 587;
client.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Send(msg); <-- Line 34
```

### Exception

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure
>   connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response
>   was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail
>   during MAIL FROM [XXXXX.namprd02.prod.outlook.com] at
>   System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode,
>   String response) at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection
>   conn, Byte[] command, MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode) at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender,
>   MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean
>   allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception) at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at line 34

Answer (score 2):

You must modify your DNS records (SPF) on the domain of the expeditor.

For exemple if the expeditor is test@mydomain.com.

You must verify the DNS TXT record of "mydomain.com", it must containt :

```
v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all
```

You can check you DNS record with this website :
https://www.whois.com.au/whois/dns.html

Enter your domain and click the button "Do live DNS lookup", the DNS records will appears.

[image]

If there is not this TXT, your must modify it...

Look this link : 
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_winother-mso_o365b/client-was-not-authenticated-to-send-anonymous/d405bcb0-f40c-42fa-b1b2-477597100123

Comment: I'm curious why I can send the email from local machine while debugging the code. However, same code with exactly same information doesn't work in Azure.

Comment: Because if I understand, when you are on local machine you use an other SMTP witch is more permissive. The office365 SMTP  need  spf.protection.outlook.com in SPF : I had the same problem.

Comment: Based on my limited understanding of SMTP, I should use `spf.protection.outlook.com` instead of `smtp.office365.com`. Is that correct? If not, could you please elaborate more in your answer that what I need to change in Office 365?

Comment: No you must use smtp.office365.com but you have to modify the DNS records of your domain

Comment: I edit my answer to explain how to check your DNS records

Comment: Thank you for your answer. According to our engineering team, we already have `include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all` in our DNS records.

Comment: Do you have try with port 25 instead of 587 ?